# Retrieved article not visible in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, knowledge, articles

I am trying to publish an article in test class and retrieve it to test some assigned variable via triggers.

Here is the code in my test class that will create the knowledge articles and then publish them (code in test class setup):

```
// create knowledge article versions to insert
        lstKnowledgeToInsert = Knowledge_TDF.createArticles(1);
        lstKnowledgeToInsert[0].UrlName = 'test12897';
        lstKnowledgeToInsert[0].OwnerId = u.Id; 
        insert lstKnowledgeToInsert;
        

        // get the knowledge articles to publish them
        lstKnowledgeToPublish = new List<Knowledge__kav>([
            SELECT
            Id, Title, KnowledgeArticleId, PublishStatus, RecordTypeId
            FROM knowledge__kav WHERE id IN :lstKnowledgeToInsert
        ]);

        // publish the knowledge
        for(Integer i = 0; i< lstKnowledgeToPublish.size(); i++){
            // here
            KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(lstKnowledgeToPublish[i].KnowledgeArticleId, true);
        }
```

I want to retrieve the updated article in my test class but the article is not yet available. Here is the code :

```
 @IsTest
public static void testChangeOwner(){

    System.runAs(myUser){
        test.startTest();
            KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle(lstKnowledgeToPublish[0].KnowledgeArticleId, true);
        test.stopTest();
        
        system.assertNotEquals(lstKnowledgeToPublish[0].KnowledgeArticleId, null,'The article id is not null');

        Knowledge__kav k = [select OwnerId from Knowledge__kav where Id =:lstKnowledgeToPublish[0].KnowledgeArticleId];

        system.assertEquals('The article owner Id has been changed to that of the running user', k.OwnerId,myUser.Id);
    }       
}
```

The test class will fail with query exception :

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

Why is the article not visible at that point in the test class ?

Comment: presumably https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205083/unable-to-publish-knowledge-article-in-apex-test-class wasn't helpful?

Comment: NO. It does not adress the same issue. My problem is that the article when retrieved using soql is not available. In the post you suggested it explain how to publish the article without changing the status via code etc..